# R Plotly set default color palette

Tags: r, plotly

In R, how do I set the default color palette for all plotly plots? 
I know in `plot_ly()` you can set `colors=palette`, but that works only for scatter plots and not for line plots. For line plots you have to set the colors for each trace individually.

Comment: If you do not get any answers here, try making a feature request.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently in the current `plotly`-version (4.8.0) this feature exists. You can set a color palette by using the `colors`-argument inside the `plot_ly()`-wrapper. However this only works if you use the `color`-argument in each `add_trace`.

```
my_palette=c('#0099FF','#00FF99') # create my palette
plot_ly(colors=my_palette) %>%    ## set the palette
  add_trace(x=1:4,y=rbinom(4,10,0.4),type='scatter',mode='lines',hoverinfo='skip',color=as.factor('my first trace')) %>% 
  add_trace(x=1:4,y=rbinom(4,10,0.5),type='scatter',mode='lines',hoverinfo='skip',color=as.factor('the second'))
```

Since the `color`-functionality is fairly new in `plotly` I am optimistic that this functionality will continue to exist in future package versions (>4.8.0.).

I only found your question over my own question and it turns out that both our problems have a [similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52179471/add-trace-control-the-color/52183900#52183900)