# add_trace: control the color

Tags: r, colors, plotly, r-plotly

I have a plot where I have first trace in gray that will be overplotted by other traces in colors. My issue is that in `plotly`-version 4.7.1. as well as in version 4.8.0. I can't adjust the color.

One year ago this code would work:

```
mysim=data.frame(x=rep(1:4,4),y=rbinom(16,10,0.5),id=rep(1:4,each=4))

my_colors<-c(             ## add the standard plotly colors
        '#1f77b4',  #// muted blue
         '#ff7f0e',  #// safety orange
         '#2ca02c',  #// cooked asparagus green
         '#d62728'  #// brick red
             ) 


plot_ly() %>%
 add_trace(x=1:4,y=rbinom(4,10,0.4),type='scatter',mode='lines',
            line=list(color='#CCCCCC',dash='dashed'),hoverinfo='skip',opacity=0.25) %>% 
  add_trace(data=mysim,x=~x,y=~y,type='scatter',mode='lines', split=~as.factor(id),
            line=list(color=my_colors),hoverinfo='skip',opacity=1)
```

Sadly I do not have that machine anymore. But it seems that there were changes made to `plotly` since then. I also tried using the `color` argument instead of `split` and used `colors` instead of the `line`-list to specify the colors. It didn't have any impact. I still get this plot: [image]

What am I missing here? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [this issue](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/790).

This works if you use `color` instead of `split` and if you set the colors in the `plot_ly` function at the beginning, with the argument `colors`:

```
plot_ly(colors=my_colors) %>%
  add_trace(x=1:4,y=rbinom(4,10,0.4),type='scatter',mode='lines', line=list(color='rgb(0,0,255)',dash='dashed'),hoverinfo='skip',opacity=0.25) %>% 
  add_trace(data=mysim,x=~x,y=~y,type='scatter',mode='lines', color=~as.factor(id),
            hoverinfo='skip',opacity=1)
```

Comment: THIS!!! I cannot believe I only now saw this - it has fixed a problem I have had for over 2 years. In this way, the `symbol` can also be set in the following manner: `symbols = c("key1" = "symbol1", "key2" = "symbol2")`. The same can be done for colors such that `colors = c("key1" = "color1", "key2" = "color2")`. This is needed when the order of the colors changes in for loops with lots of `add_trace`s. More can be seen here: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/790#issuecomment-931292330